# JQuery: using closest and find functions to show hidden div

Tags: jquery

Initially all smart-suggestion divs are hidden. I am trying to show the the 'smart-suggestions' div belonging to the closest 'prod-name-container' div that the user clicked on. I tried using closest() and find(), but it did not work and I am not sure why it isn't working.

Markup

```
              for($i=0; $i < 20; $i++){
                    echo '
                    <div class="invoice-line">
                        <div class="index">'.($i+1).'</div>
                        <div class="prod-id"><input type="text" id="prod-id"></div>
                        <div class="prod-name-container">
                           <input onKeyPress="search(this.value)" type="text" class="prod-name"/>
                           <div class="smart-suggestions">
                                <!-- RESULT SUGGESTIONS WILL POPULATE HERE -->
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="qty">1</div>
                    </div>';
                }
```

JQuery

```
   $('.smart-suggestions').hide();
   $('.prod-name').focus(function() {
        $last = $(this);
        $('.invoice-line').closest(".prod-name-container").find('.smart-suggestions').show();
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do this - .smart-suggestions is a sibling of .prod-name

```
$('.smart-suggestions').hide();
$('.prod-name').focus(function() {
    $last = $(this);
    $last.next('.smart-suggestions').show();
});
```

Comment: Perfect! exactly what I needed. Very concise, as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `next` method.

```
$(function(){ // when the DOM is ready
    $('.smart-suggestions').hide();
    $('.prod-name').focus(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.next('.smart-suggestions').show();
    });

    //  or: 
    //  $('.prod-name').on('focus blur, 'function(e) {
    //       var $this = $(this);
    //       $this.next('.smart-suggestions').toggle(e.type === 'focus');
    //  })

})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.smart-suggestions').hide();
$('.prod-name').focus(function() {
    $last = $(this);
    $('.invoice-line', $(this)).closest(".prod-name-container").find('.smart-suggestions').show();
});
```

Although if you want to have it be on click, i'd change the `$('.prod-name').focus` to .click